# How to count number of examples of a model, depending on a (given) attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks in advance for any help on this, apologies if I'm being a glaring novice.

I need to be able to count the number of examples of a model that have attribute value to that which I'm searching for.

e.g. If I had a model 'zoo' with many 'animals', how could I count the number of 'animals' within a 'zoo', with the 'name' attribute of 'gorilla'?

I'm pretty sure I know how the function would look on paper but, being very new to rails, I'm not confident in implementing it, or even sure that there isn't a simple, built in option. Selecting by name attribute & then .size-ing the selection, for example?

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zoo.animals.where(:name => 'Gorilla').count
```

If you're new to rails, you should read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html). For what you're asking, you'll find it (and a lot more!) in the [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).